# recursion value being repeated in python

Tags: python, recursion

```py
def sequence(n):
    while n!=1:
        print(n)
        if n%2==0:
            sequence(n/2)
        else:
            sequence(n*3+1)


sequence(53)
```

This loop is not terminating. I don't understand why.

Comment: You never change `n` inside your function so the `while` loop never terminates. Perhaps you meant `if n != 1:`?

Comment: You don't need both a `while` loop *and* recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the while loop. You don't need that as the recursive function is doing its job.

Here is the corrected version of your code:

```
def sequence(n):
        print(n)
        
        if n == 1:
            return
        elif n%2==0:
            sequence(n//2)
        else:
            sequence(n*3+1)


sequence(53)
```

Change the `n/2` to `n//2` so that it doesn't become a float.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence will end at 2, 2, 2, 2, 2... because no matter what `n` equals at first, it *will* go down to `2`, and then:

```
n = 2

2 / 2 = 1     # sequence(1)
1 * 3 + 1 = 4 # sequence(4)
4 / 2 = 2     # sequence(2)
2 / 2 = 1     # sequence(1)
1 * 3 + 1 = 4 # sequence(4)
4 / 2 = 2     # sequence(2)
...           # ....
```